# Работа с событиями и делегирование JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как решить данный вопрос. Существует неопределённое количество элементов a и при нажатий на а требуется выводить изображение, при нажатий вновь это изображение снова скрывать. Как можно реализовать такую штуковину?

```js
var one = document.querySelectorAll('.one a');

for(var i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
 one[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  var four = document.querySelector('.four');
  if(four.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
   four.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else if(four.style.visibility == 'visible'){
   four.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
 })
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
<h3>First</h3>
<div class="two"><img src="../../../img/1_1.png" alt="1"></div>
<a class="three" href="#">показать</a>
<img class="four" style="visibility:hidden;" src="../../../img/1_1_result.png" alt="1_result">
</div>
<div class="one">
<h3>Second</h3>
<div class="two"><img src="../../../img/1_1.png" alt="1"></div>
<a class="three" href="#">показать</a>
<img class="four" style="visibility:hidden;" src="../../../img/1_1_result.png" alt="1_result">
</div>
```

Понятно что данный код реализует нажатие по любому элементу а схожим с делегированием, но не знаю как возможно выводить при нажатий изображение не только в первом элементе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.one a').forEach(oneA => {
  oneA.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var four = this.closest('.one').querySelector('.four');
    if (four.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
      four.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else if (four.style.visibility == 'visible') {
      four.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <h3>First</h3>
  <div class="two"><img src="../../../img/1_1.png" alt="1"></div>
  <a class="three" href="#">показать</a>
  <img class="four" style="visibility:hidden;" src="../../../img/1_1_result.png" alt="1_result">
</div>
<div class="one">
  <h3>Second</h3>
  <div class="two"><img src="../../../img/1_1.png" alt="1"></div>
  <a class="three" href="#">показать</a>
  <img class="four" style="visibility:hidden;" src="../../../img/1_1_result.png" alt="1_result">
</div>
```

Comment: @maks-maks157 `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: @maks-maks157 Пожалуйста. Успехов!